# How to move everything in a string after a certain length into a list python

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to build a function that will take everything in a string after 140 characters and move it into a new variable for a second 'tweet'.

```
tweetlength = 140
tweet = input("What do you want to tweet: ")
tweet_copy = []
tweet_2 = []

for i in tweet:
    if len(tweet) <= tweetlength:
        print(tweet)
        break
    if len(tweet) >= tweetlength:
        tweet_copy = tweet
        for x in tweet_copy [140, 280]:
            tweet_2.append(x)
            print(tweet_copy + tweet_2)
```

However I am currently getting an error saying "string indices must be integers". I need to be able to refer to everything within the list with an index value of 140-280 but it seems I can't do that while it's a string?

Comment: `tweets = [tweet[i*tweetlength:min(len(tweet),(i+1)*tweetlength)] for i in range(ceil(len(tweet)/float(tweetlength)))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using python, you don't have to loop through a string. Your code can be as simple as (assuming your input is at most 280, as you do in your original example):

```py
tweetlength = 140
tweet = input("What do you want to tweet: ")
tweet, tweet_2 = (tweet[:tweetlength], tweet[tweetlength:])
print(tweet)
if tweet_2:  # An empty string evaluates as False
    print('Second part')
    print(tweet_2)
```

Comment: What if the input length is greater than 280?

Comment: That is not what was asked in the original question, but you could solve it with a while loop and append each tweet in a list, while you consume `tweetlength` sized chunks of the tweet.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a substring starting at position 140.

In snippet below "sub_s" will have the value "fg"

```
s = "abcdefg"
sub_s = s[5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generator like this:

```
MAXTWEET = 140

def tweets(user_input):
  while user_input:
    yield user_input[:MAXTWEET]
    user_input = user_input[MAXTWEET:]

for tweet in tweets('A very long string'):
  print(tweet)
```

In this way the input string can be of any length and the generator will return strings of, at most, MAXTWEET length